# Pset4 (cs50) recover does not work properly. It compiles, but does not recover more than 2 jpegs. Is something wrong with checking for JPEG signature?

Tags: c, jpeg, cs50

I am learning how to code and I have no experience with that at all. I've successful got to PSET4 and stuck on recover. I've read everything online about this problem and i found out that many people have similar code as I do and it works. Does not work for me whatsoever. Please have a look and give me a hint what did I do wrong and how to correct it.
Here is everything about the pset4 [recover](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/recover/recover.html) i downloaded their card.raw from here [card.raw](http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/psets/4/pset4/card.raw)

```
/** recovering JPEG files from a memory card
* 
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: ./recover infile (the name of a forensic image from which to recover JPEGs)\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // open input file (forensic image)
    FILE* inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    FILE* outptr = NULL;

    // create a pointer array of 512 elements to store 512 bytes from the memory card
    BYTE* buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    // count amount of jpeg files found
    int jpeg = 0;

    // string for a file name using sprintf
    char filename[8] = { 0 };

    // read memory card untill the end of file
    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, inptr) != 0)
    {
        // check if jpeg is found
        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff
            && (buffer[3] >= 0xe0 || buffer[3] <= 0xef))
        {
            if (jpeg > 0)
            {
                fclose(outptr);
            }
            sprintf(filename, "%03d.JPEG", jpeg);
            outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
            jpeg++;
        }

        if (jpeg > 0)
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, outptr);
        }
    }

    // free memory
    free(buffer);

    // close filename
    fclose(outptr);

    // close input file (forensic image)
    fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a [cs50 stackexchange](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) if you're interested.

Comment: are you saying I should use some other data type? I honestly don't understand. I know about cs50stackexchange. I think I read almost everything there and I feel like I am going crazy

Comment: `typedef uint8_t BYTE;` - what's the problem using `uint8_t` and **nmot** obfuscate your code? And which language is that supposed to be? Looks like C, so why did you add the tag of another, different language? Finally: read [ask]. We are not a debugging service.

Comment: @Stargateur: A byte **can** be an octet very well. It just depends on the rachitecture. Apparently OP wants an 8 bit byte. The standard type is correct, yet the `typedef` as such is questionable. `char` has "problematic" signed-ness, i.e. it is implementation defined. Recommending to use `char` for arithmetic usage is a very bad idea. **at least** use `unsigned char`.

Comment: I tried unsigned char before and it did not work. Just tried char and now it does not accept my IF condition ((buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] >= 0xe0 || buffer[3] <= 0xef))

Comment: @Oxi_Bo: Just use `uint8_t`, this it the type you **want** to use. Remove the `typedef`; it is superfluous and potentially missleading. For the rest: use your debugger!

Comment: I am very confused because I saw many similar codes with the same typedef and similar algorithm and the guys say everything works. I usually try figure it out all by myself but this time I am just helpless and need some help

Comment: The PSET4 spec says "Specifically, the first three bytes of JPEGs are
0xff 0xd8 0xff from first byte to third byte, left to right. The fourth byte, meanwhile, is either 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, of 0xef.
Here is everything about the pset4 http://docs.cs50.net/problems/recover/recover.html
i downloaded their card.raw from here http://cdn.cs50.net/2016/fall/psets/4/pset4/card.raw

Comment: i also tried this -     if(buffer[0]==0xff&&buffer[1]==0xd8&&buffer[2]==0xff&&(buffer[3]&0xf0)==0xe0)
I actually tried many ways to check for the first 4 bytes but I still recover only two jpegs

Comment: well, NO, the posted code does NOT compile!.  Amongst other problems, the posted code is missing the needed `#include` statements.   Do you expect us to guess as to which header files (if any) are actually being included?

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: ./recover infile (the name of a forensic image from which to recover JPEGs)\n");`   There is nothing forcing the executable name to be: `recover`  So much better/flexible to write: `fprintf(stderr,
            "Usage: %s infile (the name of a forensic image from which to recover JPEGs)\n", argv[0] );

Comment: when outputting an error message about a error indication returned from a system function, it is best to use: `perror()` as that will also output the text indicating why the system thinks the function call failed.

Comment: from the user view point, this code block results in the program silently failing: `if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        return 3;
    }`   suggest: `if (buffer == NULL)
    {  perror( "malloc failed");
        return 3;
    }

Comment: the posted code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. the returned values 1, 2, 3 and 512.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest giving those 'magic' numbers meaningful names (via `enum` or `#define` statements.)  Then using those meaningful names through out the code.

Comment: the expression `sizeof(char)`  (or in this case: `sizeof(BYTE)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect so this line: `BYTE* buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * 512);`  would be much clearer as: `BYTE* buffer = malloc( 512);`

Comment: regarding: `char filename[8] = { 0 };`  1) this only allows for 7 character file names.  2) While the 'implicit conversion' feature can save you.  The `0` is an integer and you really want NUL ('\0') characters.  Suggest: `char filename[8] = { '\0' };

Comment: this line: `while (fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, inptr) != 0)` is cluttered with the expression: `sizeof( BYTE )`.  Suggest removing that expression

Comment: this expression: `(buffer[3] >= 0xe0 || buffer[3] <= 0xef)` actually allows `buffer[3]` to be any value.  Perhaps what you meant was: `(buffer[3] >= 0xe0 && buffer[3] <= 0xef)`  which limits the allowed value to the range: `0xe0 ... 0xef`

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (and if not successful, call `perror()` to handle that error.

Comment: regarding this statement: `fwrite(buffer, sizeof(BYTE) * 512, 1, outptr);`  1) note prior comment about the expression: `sizeof(BYTE)`  2) always check the returned value from `fwrite()` to assure the operation was successful.  3 do not use `512`, rather use the actual number of bytes read,  suggest: modify `fread()` to return the number of bytes read and use that returned value as the count for the call to `fwrite()`

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to force the OS to cleanup after a program, so each point in the posted code where there is an 'error' exit, the posted code should close any open files, free any allocated memory, etc.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. I will keep it in mind. I was writing the code according to the given specification (there is a link in my question). I am kind of limited to that. Also, Ive been coding two months only, just learning how to do that.
Anyway, my code works now and I can open all the 50 images successfully.

Comment: I just added the #include statements. I guess I did not paste the program correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you invoke undefined behavior because `filename` is not enough big. `sprintf()` need be 9 and 17 bytes with your code but you only has 8. So you have a buffer overflow.

Just change:

```
char filename[8] = { 0 };
```

to

```
char filename[17] = { 0 };
```

Because, you use an `int`, this value is implemented defined but in **many** system has an `int` with 32 bits. So the value possible are between `-2^31` and `2^31 - 1` that make a maximum of 11 `char`s (-2147483648). We add the number of `char`s in ".JPEG", 5. We have 16 but you forget the null terminate byte of a c-string. So we are 17 maximum.

Modern compiler warning you: gcc version 7.1.1 20170516 (GCC):

```
In function ‘main’:
  warning: ‘sprintf’ writing a terminating nul past the end of the destination [-Wformat-overflow ]
  sprintf(filename, "%03d.JPEG", jpeg++);
                              ^
note: ‘sprintf’ output between 9 and 17 bytes into a destination of size 8
  sprintf(filename, "%03d.JPEG", jpeg++);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Plus, your `typedef` is useless because a `char` world be always a byte in C. More than that you don't need a byte but an octet so like `char`, `uint8_t` would be always an octet in C. So you don't need `typedef`.

Again one thing, you allocate your buffer but it's useless because your buffer has a constant size. So just create an array is more simple.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover infile (the name of a forensic image "
                    "from which to recover JPEGs)\n");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *inptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (inptr == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }

  FILE *outptr = NULL;
  uint8_t buffer[512];
  size_t const buffer_size = sizeof buffer / sizeof *buffer;
  size_t jpeg = 0;
  while (fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, buffer_size, inptr) == buffer_size) {
    if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff &&
        buffer[3] == 0xe0) {
      if (outptr != NULL) {
        fclose(outptr);
      }

      char filename[26];
      sprintf(filename, "%03zu.JPEG", jpeg++);
      outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
    }
    if (outptr != NULL) {
      fwrite(buffer, sizeof *buffer, buffer_size, outptr);
    }
  }

  if (outptr != NULL) {
    fwrite(buffer, sizeof *buffer, buffer_size, outptr);
  }

  if (outptr != NULL) {
    fclose(outptr);
  }

  fclose(inptr);
}
```

Note: This example is clearly not perfect, this will be better to make a true parser for jpeg file to have a better control flow. Here we suppose that all gonna be right.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed a few things in my code (got rid of memory allocation for buffer and changed char filename[17] = { 0 };, also changed while loop condition to while(fread(buffer, sizeof(BYTE)*512, 1, inptr)==1). It works and opens all the 50 files successfully though it does not pass check50 test, neither does your code. Still cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Oxi_Bo Well, when I use it on the raw file, I get the 50 valid jpeg, "To check whether the JPEGs your program spit out are correct, simply double-click and take a look! If each photo appears intact, your operation was likely a success!". I let you the rest to be conforming with the test script, tips: don't forget error reporting and "it outputs by naming each ###.jpg". By the way, if this answer solve your question don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Thank you 100 times!!!!! I was about to give up learning programming at all. I would never think it cannot pass check5o because I called the files ###.JPEG instead of ###.jpg (i just changed it and it passed check50). I was looking for some serious mistake while it was just that. Also, I really could not understand why name of the file needed 17 elements of char instead of 8.

Comment: @Oxi_Bo Oh I didn't explain it... sorry I gonna try, my English sucks :p

Comment: my English sucks as well, so if you can explain I will do my best to understand.

Comment: I just checked back to char filename [8] and it works just fine and passes check50!

Comment: @Oxi_Bo Indeed with ".jpg", you need **at least 8** `char` (only if your counter `jpeg` is between -99 and 999). But it's better to keep the max value in your buffer, so `char filename[16]`, with "%03d.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

how do you know that an instance of a JPEG image will always end with '\n'?  Or better, how do you know that a JPEG image will be an exact multiple of 512?

You dont know.

So the posted code needs to calculate the actual value OR use some method to have the last call to `fread()` for any specific JPEG instance, to stop reading at the end of that image,

Then  the check for the ID bytes of the next JPEG image will find the next image.

Otherwise, the start of the next image is already written to the prior output file and the check for a new image will fail.

In general this will result in the last created file containing more than one image.

This link: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format' is a web page that describes the format of a JPEG file.

On every digital camera that I have used, the SD card has a directory of all the files.

Suggest using that directory and the info in the linked web page to find each JPEG image and to determine when the end of that image has been encountered. (I.E. the 0xFF 0xD9)

Comment: Well, we do know that JPEG files starts the same - JPEGs have "signatures," patterns of bytes that can distinguish them from other file formats. Specifically, the first three bytes of JPEGs are 0xff 0xd8 0xff
from first byte to third byte, left to right. The fourth byte, meanwhile, is either 0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, of 0xef.

Comment: As for how i know that i have to read 512 byte - digital cameras tend to store photographs contiguously on memory cards, whereby each photo is stored immediately after the previously taken photo. Accordingly, the start of a JPEG usually demarks the end of another. However, digital cameras often initialize cards with a FAT file system whose "block size" is 512 bytes (B). The implication is that these cameras only write to those cards in units of 512 B.